# Zapier create trigger using CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, zapier

I would like to integrate my app with zapier using CLI. In this integration i want to create 2 triggers add and update .could you please anyone help me to creating triggers. I am not be clear in this concept.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad as written. There's extensive docs [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli) and an example app with a trigger [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-example-app-trigger). If you've got a specific question, feel free to ask it

Comment: You can code a Zapier action (`create`) using `inputData` from the `request` **bundle**.  The docs mentioned by xavdid should be read to understand how a create works. Basically, your Zap sends input data to the action (received from a trigger) and `create` actually executes it on the target app (using its underlying API). In the body of the `create` operation, you typically use `z.request()` and pass options such as url, method, body and headers. That's pretty much it. Knowledge of target api is very helpful.